# Difference between AWS ENI (Elastic Network Interface) and NAT Gateway in Route Table Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet

I am now trying to configure a route table for a private subnet, and I config an AWS Lambda function with these subnets. When I use an ENI, I will receive a `ssl error (violation of protocol)` when I was trying to make an API call through Internet (like a call to the ServiceNow API). When I use NAT, it works.

I investigate for a while, but still confused about when should we use ENI (or nat)? What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an AWS Lambda function is *not* connected to a VPC, it has direct access to the Internet.

When an AWS Lambda function *is* connected to a VPC, and requires access to the Internet, then the configuration should be:

- Associate the Lambda function with a **private subnet** in the VPC
- Create a **NAT Gateway** in a **public subnet**
- Configure the **Route Table** for the private subnet to route `0.0.0.0/0` traffic to the NAT Gateway

You probably received the error because the Lambda function was unable to reach the endpoint on the Internet. I don't know why you specifically received an "SSL Error".

An **Elastic Network Interface (ENI)** is the virtual network connection between a resource (eg an AWS Lambda function) and a VPC. Think of it like a 'network card' that connects it to the network.

A **NAT Gateway** is a service that does IP address translation. It accepts the local traffic and sends it to the Internet, also passing back responses. It enables Internet access from private subnets while preventing inbound access to the private subnet.

Comment: so does that mean route 0.0.0.0/0 traffic to the ENI is not enough to get the access to the Internet. We should route 0.0.0.0/0 traffic to NAT, and In NAT config, specify an ENI.

Comment: What ENI are you referencing? The ENI is where the traffic is coming _from_. ENIs are what connects resources (EC2 instances, RDS databases, Lambda functions, etc) to a VPC. The traffic coming from ENIs needs to be routed to the NAT Gateway.

Comment: got it. Thank you for your explanation

Comment: With a NAT *instance* (rather than a NAT *Gateway*) the route table target for 0.0.0.0/0 would indeed be an ENI (the one attached to the NAT instance).